# Opening Laravel links based on their Id

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-8

I've created a laravel blog and I want to open every single post on their own page using the following laravel link.

```
 <a href="{{route('about.show'.$about_us)}}" class="text-success text-decoration-none">{{$about_us->button}}</a> which I trying to open using the show method and the routes. This is how I have set up the show method and it's route.

public function show($id)
{
    //
    return view('about.show')
}

Route::get('/about.show','App\Http\Controllers\AboutController@show')->name('about.show');
```

When I try, it gives me an error Route [about.show{"id":1,"title":"My Agenda","description":"My four",... not defined.

When I try to open it up using the index method it shows but it picks up two ids. and when I delete .$about_us, it displays a blank white page. This is a noob question, but I'm struggling. Can anyone assist

Comment: You are trying to say on click of particular post it should show that complete post alone right..?

Comment: Yes. The post is also on the landing page.

Comment: It's better to create a new route which will take an Id ,based on that id you should display the particular post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your code so that's why I am giving some example how to acheive this thing.

```
Route::get('/show/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\AboutController@getPostById');
```

```
public function getPostById($id){
  $request=app('request');
  $data=Model::where('id',$request->id)->get();
  return response()->json([$data]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to accept parameter in route.
   `Route::get('/show/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\AboutController@getPostById')->name('about.show');`
2. As I see in your code your `$about_us` seems a object. So you can't pass whole object to named route as parameter. Instead do like..
   `<a href="{{route('about.show', $about_us->id)}}" class="text-success text-decoration-none">{{$about_us->button}}</a>`
3. And then finally in your `getPostById()` function, you can accept that id variable.
   `public function getPostById($id){dd($id);}`